# Filter based on size in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to filter the records in hive based on size,how can this be achieved?
Please help.

Query

```
SELECT 
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk,
    COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title) as all_measure_desc,
    size( COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title)) as ps
FROM qms_gic_lifecycle t1 
INNER JOIN dim_member t2 
on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
INNER JOIN dim_quality_measure t3 
on t1.quality_measure_id = t3.quality_measure_id
where t1.status <> 'closed'

GROUP BY  
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are having **ps** field with size value use your query as sub query, then use where clause with **ps** field to filter only  matched rows.

```
hive> Select * from (
SELECT 
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk,
    COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title) as all_measure_desc,
    size( COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title)) as ps
FROM qms_gic_lifecycle t1 
INNER JOIN dim_member t2 
on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
INNER JOIN dim_quality_measure t3 
on t1.quality_measure_id = t3.quality_measure_id
where t1.status <> 'closed'

GROUP BY  
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk) s 
    where s.ps >= <size_value>;
```